# ¿Cómo hacer un if según el tiempo de reproducción de un audio?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo un simple `<audio>`, ¿cómo podría hacer un `if` según el minuto en que va la reproducción del video?

Ejemplo:

```
if (audio.segundoTranscurrido >= 60) {

    // algo

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer exactamente?

Comment: Editado alvaro montoro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es `currentTime` que devuelve el tiempo transcurrido en el audio. Entonces lo que harías sería comprobar cada X tiempo, por dónde va el audio y si ha pasado la duración que quieres, que haga algo (también sería conveniente que tuvieses alguna variable que sirva de bandera para que no ejecutes lo mismo múltiples veces).

Algo como esto:

```js
var audioe = document.getElementById("campana");
var mensaje = false;
var intervalo;

audioe.onloadeddata = function() {
  audioe.play();
  intervalo = setInterval(comprobar5Segundos, 1000);
};

function comprobar5Segundos() {
  if (audioe.currentTime > 5 && !mensaje) {
    mensaje = true;
    console.log("LLEGASTE AL SEGUNDO 5");
    clearInterval(intervalo);
  }
}
```

```html
<audio src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2185&type=mp3" id="campana" />
```

Answer (score 1):

no sabía que el dom tenia esas posibilidades

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Por si alguien lo necesita :)

lo solucioné asignandole un ID al audio, creando una variable a este id y aplicando las funciones del dom al

```
var cancion = $("#congelado");

if (cancion.currentTime >= 30) {
//algo
}
```